# Caching 99% of my MVC3 pages

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an index web page on my site. 99% of the page is the same for every user. The 1% different is the div that says "Welcome John" or "Welcome Tony". I would love to have the benefit of caching but also would like to personalize the pages. Is there any way I could do this with MVC3?

Can I for example just cache a partial part of the page rather than the whole page so as to speed things up?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about partial-page output caching at [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx).  (Search for "Partial Page Output Caching")

Comment: you are absolutely right. partial page can cahce. I'm sort of dork,  didn't see the forest for the trees on this one. :) thanks